# Select dictionary keys and put them into a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I would be very happy if somebody could help me solve the following exercise about dictionaries.

Write a function that takes a dictionary where every key is a string and the value is a whole number (integer) and returns a sorted list of the keys corresponding to their even numbers.

Example

```
dictionary = {'Kurt':35, 'Alex':26, 'Laura':31}
```

Should return

```
mylist= ['Alex'] # because it's the only key that has a matching even number
```

This is my code

```py
def even_numbers (mydict):

    mylist = []
    for num in mydict.values():
        if num % 2 == 0:
            mylist.append(mydict.keys())

return mylist
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

use `dict.items` instead of `dict.values`:

```py
def even_numbers (mydict):
    mylist = []
    for key, num in mydict.items():
        if num % 2 == 0:
                mylist.append(key)

    return mylist
```

when you do `mylist.append(mydict.keys())` you'll have a list of keys for every pair value, so the need of using `dict.items` which return an iterable of `key, value` pair

Comment: Maybe give some content to explain to the OP ?

Comment: I was so close!. Thank you very much